# How can I put the icon and tag in the same line?

Tags: javascript, css, html, ionic-framework

The icon and the word hi can not be put into the same line

[image: screenshot of the problem]

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h5 class="title">hi</h5> 
  </div>
  <i class="icon ion-ios-heart"></i>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1** - CSS

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="item">
            <h5 style="display:inline" class="title">hi</h5>
            <i class="icon ion-ios-heart"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2** - In same column

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h5 class="title">hi<i class="icon ion-ios-heart"></i></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 3** - In two columns in same row

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h5 class="title">hi</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-heart"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

h5 will display as a block, so it has its own line.

Should work with the icon inside the h5 tags, though.

---